# Removing an event listener that requires an argument

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have:

```
e.addEventListener("click",()=>{alert(this.innerText);});
```

and I need to be able to remove it.

If I don't use an anonymous function so that I can use `removeEventListener`, how to I pass `this` to the named function?

```
function f() { 
   //how do I access the "this"?
}
e.addEventListener("click", f);
```

Comment: you could assign "this" - element that has click, to a global array, that keeps the track of things with custom ID's and the arrayelm.removeListener I guess.

Comment: same as you accessed it before. you didn't pass `this` to the anonymous one either. It just happens due to the way JS works. http://jsfiddle.net/oh3adru1/

Comment: Maybe try `event.srcElement` and add `event` as an argument to your function?

Comment: You can also use `const f = () => {...}` so that your `this` behave the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem you have is that you don't have any handle on your function since you're declaring it inline. All you need to do is move that same declaration and assign it to a variable:

```
const cb = () => alert(this.innerText);
e.addEventListener('click', cb);
e.removeEventListener('click', cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just create a friendlier function to work with.

```
const listen = (el, ...args) => {
    el.addEventListener(...args);
    return{
        remove: () => el.removeEventListener(...args)
    };
};
```

So you can just do things like...

```
const listener = listen(document, 'click', () => {
    console.log('click');
    listener.remove();
});
```